# Problem of instance v-show - Nuxt js menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to do a simple menu for mobile, but I didn't solve a problem of instance of vue

#### My component nuxt Menu :

```js
<template>
    <header id="menu" class="menu-g">
        <Nuxt-link to="/"><img src="~assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo de Lucas"/></Nuxt-link>
        <div v-show="open">
          <Nuxt-link to="/projets">Projets</Nuxt-link>
          <Nuxt-link to="/articles">Articles</Nuxt-link>
          <Nuxt-link to="/a-propos">À propos</Nuxt-link>
          <Nuxt-link to="#mecrire">M'écrire</Nuxt-link>
        </div>
        <div @click="menu()">Menu</div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: {
            open: true,
        },
        methods: {
            menu: function() {
                this.ouvert = false
            }
        },
    }
    
</script>
```

#### My error

[image]

Comment: also triggering `menu()` on click it sets `this.ouvert = false` not `this.open = true`

Comment: Replacing with `data: () => ({ open: true }),` should fix it :)

Comment: Mainly, you can't use (or mutate) a state if you did not have it already defined somewhere in your `script` section. Also, I recommend writing code in English even if you're french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for each instance to maintain an independent copy of it's data, the `data` option must be a function that returns an object.

So in your code snippet, just update to:

```js
export default {    
  data: () => ({
    open: true,   
  }),
}
```

For more info, see **[`data` Must Be a Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html?redirect=true#data-Must-Be-a-Function)** in the Vue docs.

---

Side-note, as mentioned by Lawrence, you've got a small typo in the menu open function (`ouvert` --> `open`).
If you want to toggle the menu, you can do something like:

```
methods: {
  menu() { // Toggle menu open state
    this.open = !this.open;
  },
}
```